# The program crashes when running strlen() written in assembly with SSE4.2 instructions

Tags: assembly, sse, strlen

My program is below and I want to use it to calculate the length of a string.

```
.CODE
EQUAL_EACH = 1000b
strlen_sse PROC
string equ [esp+4]
mov ecx, string
;ecx = string
mov eax, -16
mov edx, ecx
pxor xmm0, xmm0

STRLEN_LOOP:
    add eax, 16
    PcmpIstrI xmm0, xmmword ptr [edx+eax], EQUAL_EACH
    jnz STRLEN_LOOP

add eax, ecx
ret

strlen_sse ENDP
END
```

It always crashes when I run it. What caused this?
[image]

The `main` is like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
extern "C" int strlen_sse(const char* src);

int main(){
    DWORD start,stop;
    char* str = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";
    start = GetTickCount();
    for (; i < 100000000; i++) {
        strlen_sse(str);
    }
    stop = GetTickCount();
    printf("%lld ms\n",stop-start);
}
```

My working environment is `visual studio 2015 community`, the platform of the project is `x64(active)`, there is not any errors when I compile it.

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Did you check the alignment of the string you pass in?

Comment: The error still exists when I change my `str` to meet the alignment, I changed it to `"asdfasdfasdfasd"` which is 16 bytes long.

Comment: But is it aligned on 16 bytes (i.e. are the 4 least signficant bits of the string's address all zero)?

Comment: If you write assembler code, and you can't get it to work, then you need to switch to C or some higher level code. The alternative is to persevere; find what debugging tools you have, download the instruction manuals from Intel's website and so on.

Comment: That looks slow (because the SSE4.2 string instructions still aren't fast, several generations after being introduced).  Maybe try `pcmpeqb` with a zeroed register, and either `PTEST / jcc` or `pmovmsk / test/jcc`.  `PcmpIstrI` is [4 uops with a memory operand, with a throughput of one per 3 cycles](http://agner.org/optimize), on Intel Haswell.

Answer (score 1):

The C code is probably compiled to 64bit code, and the assembly is 32 bit code. Having 32 bit code in a 64 bit code segment will not work.

Change the assembly to this (I removed unnecessary code aswell):

```
.CODE
EQUAL_EACH = 1000b
strlen_sse PROC
    mov rax, -16
    mov rdx, [rsp + 8]
    pxor xmm0, xmm0

    STRLEN_LOOP:
        add rax, 16
        PcmpIstrI xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdx+rax], EQUAL_EACH
        jnz STRLEN_LOOP

    add rax, rcx
    ret

strlen_sse ENDP
END
```

Comment: Setting eax zeros the upper32 of rax, so on hit first iteration, eax = 0 with his original code.  You don't need the -16 sign-extended into rax because eax becomes non-negative before it's used as an index in an addressing mode.  You're right about rsp and rdx, though.

Comment: I use `ml64 /c %(filename).asm` to compile the assembly, so I think the assembly code is 64 bit, though I used 32bit regs. Isn't it?

Comment: It may very well be put in a 64 bit segment, but you're still addressing the stack (`esp`) and heap (`[edx+eax]`) using 32 bit registers, which loses half of the address information, causing a segmentation/addressing fault.